# What is this simple mechanism called?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, soft-question, terminology

I often build with Lego and use this mechanism:

[image: Mech]

It converts the rotational movement to linear by making the stick between the two blocks go back and forth.

What is this mechanism called?

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piston

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming a device, and not physics.

Comment: Isn't science and physics also about using the correct terminology?

Comment: @Murplyx [english.se] perhaps?

Comment: @ACuriousMind From a quick search of [meta], I think [terminology questions like this are on-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1083/37545).

Comment: @TimS: I don't, from the post you linked, as Qmechanic states: *"'What is the standard notation for this quantity?' or 'Why do we use this notation?' is off-topic/not constructive"* and asking for the *name* of something strikes me as very akin to "What is the standard notation?".

Comment: My (personal, not moderator-power) opinion is that this is not a physics questions. This mechanism is a perfectly ordinary piece of mechanical equipment. Asking about specialized lab equipment would be one thing, but what is there about this thing that makes *Physics* the right site for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a "crank and slider" or "slider-crank" mechanism.